# My CSS isn't being loaded into my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that I'm constructing from following a tutorial. I've applied the correct code for the application, and all of its parts and files are in order. But when I try to load the webpage, I notice that the CSS isn't being applied to the webpage. Here is what I have so far with the code for the HTML and CSS.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="x-UTF-16LE-BOM">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Vesco Portfolio</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Condensed?selection.family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Vesco!</h1>

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a possibility that my browser (or computer) is bad or has malware on it? Or should I just try using a different browser (I'm using Google Chrome and Firefox)?

[image]

Comment: why dont check the browser whether ur css is correctly refer?

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of your website.

Comment: While nothing is impossible, I've never heard of malware that causes browsers to misbehave like this. It's 99% probability that you did something wrong.

Comment: If everything's gonna correct, then just refresh your browser cache. In my case, after refreshing cache storage I've got the stylesheets... That's it

Comment: I tried refreshing the browser cache. It didn't make the program work.

Comment: Open the console on your browser and see if it reports any errors such as not finding the file. Also, it's a relative path, so is the css directory in the same directory as this file is? And what about the formatting of the content of the css file? Maybe that could be the problem? hard to know..

Comment: @CMiller I tried looking into the app through the developer tools, and strangely the css code isn't even loaded. It just has the default html code on it.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of the dev tools?

Comment: Well I don't imagine the CSS file is blank, but gotta at least throw it out there.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I just added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory it is in currentDirectory>css>style.css try /css/style.css, the other problem is what does the whole css file look like have you added anything to the top of it. The only thing it should have is @charset "UTF-8";. The last thing it could be is that you need to clear your cache. If you don't clear your cache the page will still render the old css sheet without the change. So go to history and clear history. Also clear cache works if you have the developer options enabled on whatever browser you are using. The best way to know if the selector is working is to change the color
like:
`body { color: red; } then troubleshoot.
I've done the same thing and usually it is either cache or path is not quite right.